# How to get the parent $index of a nested ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

anyone knows how to get the first level `$index` of a nested `ng-repeat`?

Here is my data:

```
vm.rooms = [
      {
          name: 'Room1', students: ['Cal', 'Ryan', 'Luigi', 'Joel']
      },
      {
          name: 'Room2', students: ['Jaime', 'Sherwin', 'Gami', 'Beau']
      },
      {
          name: 'Room3', students: ['Roel', 'Edwin', 'Carl', 'Necho']
      }
  ]
```

And i want to get this output:

```
Room1 - Idx: 0
    Cal - Idx: 0 on room idx: 0
    Ryan - Idx: 1 on room idx: 0
    Luigi - Idx: 2 on room idx: 0
    Joel - Idx: 3 on room idx: 0
Room2 - Idx: 1
    Jaime - Idx: 0 on room idx: 1
    Sherwin - Idx: 1 on room idx: 1
    Gami - Idx: 2 on room idx: 1
    Beau - Idx: 3 on room idx: 1
Room3 - Idx: 2
    Roel - Idx: 0 on room idx: 2
    Edwin - Idx: 1 on room idx: 2
    Carl - Idx: 2 on room idx: 2
    Necho - Idx: 3 on room idx: 2
```

But i get this one here in my [DEMO](https://codepen.io/badcoder28/pen/LWpwVQ) you can check the html structure there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use $parent to access to scope of the parent.
So use

```
$parent.$index
```

Comment: what about if a had 3 levels of nested ng-repeat? does this one still solved it

Comment: Yes, you keep chaining `$parent` to keep going up levels.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

> $parent.$index

Other simple solution is initiate index in ng-init with different variable

```
<div ng-app="app"  ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4]" ng-init="firstIndex=$index">
    <div ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4]" ng-init="secondIndex=$index">
      <div ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4]" ng-init="thirdIndex=$index">
      {{firstIndex}}:{{secondIndex}}:{{thirdIndex}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
var app=angular.module("app",[]);
app.controller("ctrl",function($scope){

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app"  ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4]" ng-init="firstIndex=$index">
    <div ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4]" ng-init="secondIndex=$index">
      <div ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4]" ng-init="thirdIndex=$index">
      {{firstIndex}}:{{secondIndex}}:{{thirdIndex}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```